# Overflow content background-color not expanding

Tags: html, css

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, but the background-color of some divs are not expanding the way I want them to. Here's a fiddle to demonstrate

https://jsfiddle.net/9kxxcc04/

```
<body><div><pre style="background-color: red">A LOT OF CONTENT THAT OVERFLOWS</pre></div></body>
```

Basically I have some div/pre blocks with overflowing content and I want their background colors to be the same the entire width of the div that they're in.

Thanks!

Comment: Text is overflowing `pre` HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line from actual-content class

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

And remove **overflow:hidden** from body.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I need that `overflow: hidden` SOMEWHERE, otherwise the .actual-content div expands past the `.content-wrapper` and `.content` divs. Any way to fix that?

Comment: yeah add  overflow: auto; => .actual-content | and |overflow: scroll; => .content-wrapper and in body overflow:hidden remove

Comment: Yup! Works. Thanks!

Comment: wc dude :) happy cssing :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS and I think it will fix the wrapping:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pre is a block level element and as such won't extend beyond it's container in this case. If you swap the display style to *inline-block* then you will get the background to overflow with the text. At least from what I understand from the fiddle.

Comment: This is close, but it adds a different problem... if one `<pre>` block's content is shorter than another, the smaller-content's background-color doesn't match with the larger-content's block. I need all of the background-colors to line up.

Comment: Just add a *min-width* of 100% and that will extend the width of the pre to at least the edge of the container while also allowing the overflow.